# Proof that $-\partial^2 G(x, y) = \delta(x-y)$ for free field propagator

Tags: field-theory, greens-functions, dirac-delta-distributions, propagator, regularization

I recently realized that there is a slightly pedantic issue when one normally proves that the equations of motion acting on the free field propagator gives a delta function which I have become confused about. In Fourier space, the Euclidean propagator is given by
$$G(x-y) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\int d^dp \frac{1}{p^2}e^{ip\cdot (x-y)}.$$
We then say
$$\begin{align}-\partial^2 G(x-y) &= -\frac{1}{(2\pi)^d}\partial_\mu\int d^dp \frac{i p^\mu}{p^2}e^{i p\cdot (x-y)}\\
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^d} \int d^dp \frac{p^2}{p^2} e^{ip\cdot x} = \delta(x-y).\end{align} $$
My issue is that in going to the second line, we pulled a derivative inside of a conditionally convergent integral. Of course, the final answer is correct, but is there a straightforward reason why one doesn't need to be worried about this potential issue?

Comment: Since the Dirac delta function is a distribution anyway, you should really multiply the entire calculation by some normalisable function $f(x)$ and then integrate over $x$. When integrated against such functions, all integrals are convergent and this manipulation is valid.